# String en formato yyyyMMddHHmmss a DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

Estoy intentando convertir una cadena de String a DateTime pero me da el siguiente error:

> System.FormatException: 'La cadena representa un DateTime no admitido en el calendario System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.'

Esto es lo que estoy intentando

```
List<DateTime> fechas = new List<DateTime>();
fechas.Add(DateTime.ParseExact(strings[i], "yyyyMMddmmHHss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

El tipo de valor que le paso es algo como esto: `"20190601083158"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En el ejemplo que dejas, tiene sentido el error.

Si lo leemos de la siguiente manera, creo que será mucho más fácil notarlo

```
+---------+-----------+
| Formato | Resultado |
+---------+-----------+
| yyyy    |      2019 |
| MM      |        06 |
| dd      |        01 |
| mm      |        08 |
| HH      |        31 | <- ERROR
| ss      |        58 |
+---------+-----------+
```

Creo que viéndolo de esta manera, te vas a dar cuenta a simple vista lo que esta provocando el error.

Dentro de C#, en un objeto `DateTime` la hora puede oscilar entra 0 y 23, por eso, al intentar usar `DateTime.ParseExact` se dispara un [FormatException](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.formatexception.-ctor?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.FormatException.%2523ctor);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) (ya que es imposible traducir el número 31 a una hora válida).

Asumiendo que fué un error a la hora de tipear el string del formato, y el penúltimo valor representa los minutos, podemos parsearlo de la siguiente manera:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("20190601083158", "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Lo que produciría el siguiente objeto DateTime

> Día 01, Mes 06, Año 2019
>
> Hora 08 Minuto 31 Segundo 58

<sup><sub>*Lo tipee para evitar la confusión por la representación de la fecha en distintas culturas*</sub></sup>

Comment: Vaya tela, que fallo más tonto  ‍♂️ pensé que lo tenía bien puesto. Gracias.